# How to encrypt a file using gpg key from files in Go?

Tags: go, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I'm doing some works about secure communication. I generated a gpg key in the bash. It is easy to encrypt a file in the bash, however, I want to do that in Go.

The go package openpgp seems not having relative functions, so how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look on [this sample code](https://gist.github.com/ayubmalik/a83ee23c7c700cdce2f8c5bf5f2e9f20) .

Comment: Thank you very much, Kamol Hasan. This example solved my problem perfectly!